# How to make child pass array (from db) to parent

Tags: javascript, arrays

How come there is nothing show up. No error, just nothing show up.

App.js is below:

```
import { PriceRangeData } from './PriceRangeData.js';
import { variables } from './Variables.js';
import React, { Component, useState, useEffect } from "react";

function App() {
    const [priceRangesState, setPriceRangesState] = useState([]);
    const [checkPriceRangesState, setCheckPriceRangesState] = useState([]);

    const childToParent = (childdata) => {
        setPriceRangesState(childdata);
    }

    const handlePriceRangesCheckbox = (e) => {

        const value = e.target.value;
        if (e.target.checked) {
            setCheckPriceRangesState([...checkPriceRangesState, value]);
        } else {
            setCheckPriceRangesState(checkPriceRangesState.filter(item => item !== value));
        }       
    }

    return (
        <>
            {priceRangesState.map(p => <div>{<input key={p.id} type='checkbox' value={p.lowPrice} onChange={handlePriceRangesCheckbox} />} ${p.lowPrice} - ${p.highPrice}</div>)}
        </>
    )

}

export default App;
```

---

PriceRangeData.js is below:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { variables } from './Variables.js';

export class PriceRangeData extends Component {  



constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {            
        employees: []
    }
}

componentDidMount() {
    this.getPriceRanges();
}    

getPriceRanges() {      

    fetch(variables.API_URL, {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
    })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
            this.setState({ employees: data });              
        },
        (error) => {
            alert('Failed');
        })        
}   

render() {              
    return {employees}         
}

}
```

I am trying to get a list of (array) of data from child (PriceRangeData.js) which get data from the database. And then pass this data to parent (App.js) so that the parent can display this data.

When I run my it, there is nothing show up, not even error.

Please let me know how can I fix it. Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: this smells like chatgpt, how is it possible that you wrote all that code without realizing sooner it was not working as expected?